# How to PHP debug multiple websites in VS Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

**Expected behavior:**

I have multiple PHP projects on different servers, usually I debug them with PhpStorm which allows me to configure path mappings for remote debugging per server. Thus I can have the same remote paths e.g. `/var/www/html` for different servers.

**Problem description:**

So far I have been unable to configure multiple servers with the same remote paths using VSCode.

I use the most used [php-debug plugin](https://github.com/felixfbecker/vscode-php-debug) for VSCode and have not found any information regarding this issue on the projects [GitHub page](https://github.com/felixfbecker/vscode-php-debug) or anywhere else.

Currently I do not think configuring multiple remote servers using VSCode is possible at this time but in case someone knows a way I would appreciate it.

**Current configuration:**

With the following configuration I can only debug one project at once and have to change the paths manually when I want to debug another project on another server with the same remote paths.

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Listen for XDebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9000,
        "pathMappings": {
            "/var/www/html": "/local/project/path",
            "/var/www/html/src/shared:": "/local/shared/src/path",
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Launch currently open script",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "port": 9000
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1**

To debug multiple websites with VSCode first add multiple configurations to the [vscode-php-debug](https://github.com/felixfbecker/vscode-php-debug) extensions config (Run->Open Configurations) with different names.

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "website 1",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9000,
        "pathMappings": {
            "/var/www/html": "/local/project/path1",
        }
    },
           {
        "name": "website 2",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9000,
        "pathMappings": {
            "/var/www/html": "/local/project/path2",
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "website 3",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9000,
        "pathMappings": {
            "/var/www/html": "/local/project/path3",
        }
    },
]
}
```

**Step 2**

You then have to select the appropriate configuration **before** debugging your code by clicking on the current configuration in the bottom left hand corner or writing debug in the top bar (ctrl+t and remove the hash) (which will make that configuration the default for the current session and immediately launch debugging).